# Form perdendo a lista do model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, fluent-nhibernate

Tenho os seguintes models:

**Models**

```
public class Atividade : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao{ get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Anotacao> Anotacoes{ get; set; }
}

public class Anotacao : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int Id{ get; set; }
    public virtual Atividade Atividade{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Motivo{ get; set; }
}
```

O problema é quando estou alterando minha atividade
minha lista de Anotacoes é perdida toda vez que vou salvar.
como posso resolver esse problema?

**View**

```
@model SPACE.Model.Atividade
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarAtividade", "Atividade", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formAtividade" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-body">
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descricao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descricao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                            <small>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descricao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</small>
                        </div>

                    <hr />

                    <div class="form-actions" align="right">
                            <a href="@Url.Action("GridAtividade", "Atividade", new { Area = "Cadastro" })" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect waves-light">
                                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>

                        <button type="button" id="btn-salvar-atividade" title="Sem permissão de usuário." class="btn btn-success" onclick="validaDataHora();"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> Salvar</button>
                    </div>
                }
```

**Scripts**

```
    $("#btn-salvar-atividade").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var formAtividade = $("#formAtividade").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //contentType: "application/json",
            url: "@Url.Action("SalvarAtividade", "Atividade", new { area = "Cadastro" })",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                model: formAtividade
            }),
            success: function (data) {
                return msg("Salvo com sucesso");
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SalvarAtividade(Atividade model)
{
      using (var save = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                _session.SaveOrUpdate(model);

                save.Commit();

                return new RetornoSalvarDto { Model = model, ERetornoCrud = ERetornoCrud.Sucesso };
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                save.Rollback(); 
                _session.Clear();

                string error = "Ops! Ocorreu um problema ao tentar salvar." + e.Message;

                return new RetornoSalvarDto { Model = model, ERetornoCrud = ERetornoCrud.Erro };
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Poderia descrever maiores detalhes do seu método que está salvando? Provavelmente voce está salvando um objeto que não está atachado a sua sessão e com isso ele retira todos os joins com as atividades que estavam antes.

Comment: Atualizado com meu método salvar... Porem já ao chegar o parâmetro já chega no salvar com a lista zerada...

Comment: Poste detalhes da RetornoSalvarDto também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posso pontuar duas situações aqui.

1) Quando você submete o FORM, ele manda todos os valores que estão em componentes dentro dele, como por exemplo o que você fez com o item:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
```

Que quando isso é renderizado em HTML, é criado um:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="?" />
```

Se você quer que os valores da lista sejam enviados de volta no submeter do FORM, basta colocar os valores deles em HiddenFields com os nomes corretos.

2) O EntityFramework irá sobrescrever os objetos interligados caso você altere os valores. Se no seu caso isso não for necessário, ou seja, se esses valores nunca precisarem ser mudados, basta configurar seu EntityFramework para não alterar os objetos de tabelas relacionadas.

OBS: Na minha opinião, a maneira que você salva os dados na base tá meio estranho. O mais correto (na minha opinião) é que primeiro você consulte o objeto a ser alterado, mude nele somente os valores diferentes, e salve o objeto que você acabou de consultar. Evite persistir objetos que acabaram de vir do seu FORM, só por segurança.

OBS²: Acabei falando EntityFramework e depois vi que era NHibernate. Mas a idéia é a mesma...